# Is it possible to sort lists of string elements, with respect to each other?

Tags: python-3.x, list, sorting, radix-sort

assuming i have he following list of list of list = 
`[[1, ["test"]], [2, ["array", "new", ]], [3, ["apple]], [4,["balls"]]]`

What is the most efficient way to sort this list so that  the inner most list, containing the strings, will be grouped by similar lengths and alphabetically, and assuming that the inner list of strings is already sorted alphabetically. Something like; 
`[[3, ["apple], [4,["balls"], [1, ["test"], [2, ["array", "new"]]`.

I was thinking of using a radix sort but I am unsure how to call radix sort to compare multiple lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
l =  [[1, ["test"]], [2, ["array", "new"]], [3, ["apple"]], [4,["balls"]]]
print(sorted(l,key=lambda l:(len(l[1]),l[1])))
```

Output

```
[[3, ['apple']], [4, ['balls']], [1, ['test']], [2, ['array', 'new']]]
```

Complexity of functions in python

> https://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/ICS-33/lectures/complexitypython.txt

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, just wondering what is the complexity for this?